# Android : Sort Array list of Strings containing paths of all the .jpg files on the mobile

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

Can anyone help me about how to sort array list of string containing paths.
i used Collection.sort(my_list);
but it didn't worked fine , it sorts them in order according to the folder names like suppose i have files :

```
mnt/sdcard/A.jpg
mnt/sdcard/folder1/B.jpg
mnt/sdcard/C.jpg
mnt/sdcard/folder2/D.jpg
```

after Collections.sort(my_list) :

```
mnt/sdcard/A.jpg
mnt/sdcard/c.jpg
mnt/sdcard/folder1/b.jpg
mnt/sdcard/folder2/d.jpg
```

i want results like :

```
 mnt/sdcard/A.jpg
    mnt/sdcard/folder1/B.jpg
    mnt/sdcard/C.jpg
    mnt/sdcard/folder2/D.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = new File("mnt/sdcard/c.jpg").getName();
```

returns `c.jpg`

Use it for each String in your `Collection`, in your comparator to sort the List

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom `Comparator` and pass that `comparator` object to the [sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) function. While implementing comparator,split for file path and get that last part alone. Then return the result comparing these last parts.

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to get the substring of each string after the last "/". Then you can sort by that value.

`String sub = myString.substring(string.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);`

Comment: i took a temporary list<string> and sorted it according to substring after / , the temporary list is sorted , but i am not able to find the logic to sort my path list according to this temp list , can you write the code please